# Keyboard is breaking cell of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, keyboard, cell

Im trying to create a multi step form to user create an account, so i created a UICollectionView and a cell for each step. But, when i open the keyboard, the whole cell goes up with it, and i would like that this don't happens! What I mean is, the keyboard doesn't affect the cell.

**before keyboard shows up**

[image]

**after keyboard shows up**

[image]

**Func that opens the UICollectionView**

```
  @objc private func openSignUpViewContr(){
            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            let sgnUpVC = SignUpController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            present(sgnUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)     
        }
```

Comment: Seems like you have installed IQKeyboardManager or something like that. is it true?

Comment: As far as I know, I didn't install it! Is this a common problem?

Comment: Check your PODS file once. and it depends. there are many posts on SO in which OP wants to lift the screen up-to UITextField/UITextView when keyboard appears.

Comment: Try https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding, will automatically manage the scroll up and down of textfields.

Comment: But, in my case, the whole cell is sliding up with the keyboard!! Its not the text fields

Comment: @VinniciusPereira Have you added any code that deals with updating the UI when the keyboard is shown? If you haven't added anything, it is not common behavior for the view to change on it's own when the keyboard has come up

Comment: No, i didnt, the only thing i added to my code, releated to the keyboard, is that one when you "unfocus" the text field, the the keyboard goes down. But when i use the keyboard with the view controller, it works fine, the problem is when i use UICollectionView and its cells.

Answer (score 0):

[Please refer](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

AppDelegate.swift

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    return true
 }
```

Comment: I can't use IQKeyboarManager, I didnt install it!